# How can I set a variable based on the render element $vars[‘body’][‘#object’][‘vid’]?

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

In trying to learn about theming and alter hooks. I'm looking at the render array passed to `hook_node_view_alter()` with the following code.

```
function hook_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  dpm($build);
}
```

I want to set a variable based on `$build['body']['#object']['vid'])`, but I get this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

I don't understand this error. Can someone explain it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i'm just studying it, pulling it apart. trying to learn to be an advanced themer ;-)

Comment: Remember that `hook_node_view_alter` param is passed by reference. But of course you can create a variable like this `$myVar = $build['body']['#object']['vid’];` given that the `vid` is set. After that you have to integrate everything back to `$build` in order for your hook to take in effect.

Comment: Please see my example. I hope you found it useful. https://gist.github.com/geraldvillorente/1f8bd3d3c603ea9b191831283d344809

Comment: that won't work, that generates the fatal error

Comment: See my comment. It generate fatal error because the parent is an object and I treat is as an array in my example.

Comment: This is a plain PHP question. The error message is pretty clear, considering you are even using `dpm()` to see what the `$build` variable contains. Drupal doesn't change PHP grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The #object in the $build array *is* an object, therefor it's properties have to be referenced with an arrow, ->

```
$orig_vid = $build['body']['#object']->vid;
$build['body']['#object']->orig_val = $orig_vid;
$build['body']['#object']->vid = 100;
```

thanks Gulok for answering this

Comment: this was purely an excercise in helping to understand the data used in the hook_node_view_alter function